# SQL Server 8 - speed up an insert

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to speed up an INSERT INTO in SQL Server 8 for this insert - I have anonymized the query and it's a very simple statement.

Every project is different - sometimes I need to insert 5k rows, sometimes I have to insert 250k-600k rows - it all depends on what is requested of me.  The larger inserts take a LONG time.

Is there a way to speed this up when there are larger inserts that are needed?

```
Declare @MyVariable_I as int
Set @MyVariable_I = 15


INSERT INTO ExistingTable 
            -- there is a field in this table called UID that has a clustered index on it
            -- Currently has 106.8 Million rows in it
            -- Only has 7 fields in it and they're small fields
(
    Field1            -- non-unique, non-clustered on this field already exists
    ,Field2
    ,Field3            -- non-unique, non-clustered on this field already exists
    ,Field4            -- non-unique, non-clustered on this field already exists
    ,Field5            -- non-unique, non-clustered on this field already exists
    ,Field6
    ,Field7
)
    SELECT
        Field1
        , @MyVariable_I
        ,Field3
        ,0
        ,Field5
        , NULL
        ,Field7
    FROM
        SomeOtherTable WITH (nolock) 
        -- can have anywhere from 5,000 to 250,000 rows - each project is different
```

[image: PropertiesOfTheServerImOn]

[image]

-- OK so here's my guess on how to do a batch insert
-- found this item here: http://sqlserverplanet.com/data-warehouse/transferring-large-amounts-of-data-using-batch-inserts

```
[cc lang=”sql”]
DECLARE @BatchSize int = 10000

SELECT 1                      -- @Larnu
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0          -- @Larnu
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destination] –WITH (TABLOCK) — Uncomment for 2008
(
    Field1   
    ,Field2
    ,Field3  
    ,Field4  
    ,Field5  
    ,Field6
    ,Field7
)
SELECT TOP(@BatchSize)
    SELECT
        Field1
        , @MyVariable_I
        ,Field3
        ,0
        ,Field5
        , NULL
        ,Field7
    FROM
        SomeOtherTable SOT
    ORDER BY                                      -- @Larnu
        FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3                      -- @Larnu
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (                              -- @Larnu FROM HERE DOWN
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Destination DEST
            WHERE 
                DEST.FIELD1 = SOT.FIELD1 AND 
                DEST.FIELD2 = SOT.FIELD2 AND
                DEST.FIELD3 = SOT.FIELD3 
                    )

--commented next item as it is not needed due to @Larnu suggestions
--IF @@ROWCOUNT < @BatchSize BREAK 

END 
[/cc]
```

Comment: Lots can help. Drop all your indexes and rebuild, bulk insert, rowlock, etc. What research have you done and tried?

Comment: Tried dropping indexes and recreating - sometimes this appears to be a zero sum game because it appears (and I may be wrong) that leaving the indexes and inserting takes the same time to completion as dropping, inserting and recreating indexes.

Comment: And be careful using that nolock hint. Are you ok with missing some rows or even getting duplicates? That hint will do that as well as a number of other quite interesting anomalies that are incredibly difficult if not impossible to reproduce/debug. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Clustering a table on UIDs is not good in my experience. It causes data page splits which is a pretty big hit in large inserts.

Comment: For big groups you may want to do your inserts in batches. Maybe around 10-20k rows at a time. That reduces the sizes of the transaction and eases pressure on the transaction log.

Comment: @JamesZ not quite true. SQL Server 8.0 was SQL Server 2000. I hope, however, that isn't the version the OP is using. :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean not just your experience. Using a guid for a clustered index is very bad idea. Kimberly Tripp has a great article on the topic here. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Comment: Added an image that shows the version of SQL Server I'm using - unless this is the incorrect location to find the version.

Comment: Pretty sure that is sql 2000 sp4. Any chance you get upgrade that dinosaur? sql 2000 has been out of support for nearly a decade now. Consider that sql 2005 and sql 2008 are out of support and you get an idea of how out of date this really is.

Comment: To pile on with what @SeanLange is saying, Windows NT 5.2 is effectively Windows XP. That's been out of support since 2014 as well. You really need to be putting that server to bed now and updating to far more recent technology. Running unsupported Software on an unsupported Operating System is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Can you provide the table design + indexes + constraints for the table you are inserting into?

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu and SeanLange.  That is something that is SUPPOSED to be being looked at as time and other projects permit

Comment: @SeanLange and UnhandledExcepSean - The UID that is clustered is just an INT 4 identity

Comment: BTW - I inherited this code and the table and its indexes and all its attributes from someone who is no longer here and have not had time to fix it except for tiny little tweaks as I can wedge them in.

Comment: Back on topic....the performance of inserting 600k rows in a single insert statement is going to be horrible. The way around this is doing batch inserts.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - I Added properties of table as requested (table design + indexes + constraints)

Comment: All - I put in what I think would be the correct way to do a batch insert - see posting above - LMK what you think.  Honest and harsh criticism is **welcomed** regarding my "bulk insert" attempt :-)

Comment: As it stands, that isn't going to work as intended. Your `TOP(@BatchSize)` is just going to keep returning a dataset of random (due to no `ORDER BY`) rows the size of `@BatchSize` indefinitely. You'll need to use some kind of `WHERE` clause or similar, to ensure you don't reinsert rows you've already inserted. Unfortunately, due to using a (very) old version of SQL Server, you don't have the luxury of using `OFFSET` and `FETCH`.

Comment: Also, personally, I'm not a fan of `WHILE 1=1` and `BREAK`. I would prefer to do `WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0` and put a `SELECT 1` prior to the `WHILE` (meaning that the `WHILE` can be entered, as `@@ROWCOUNT` would have a value of `1` prior to the first iteration).

Comment: Hi @Larnu - thanks for the comments and critique! - I made mods to my bulk insert based on your comments - please LMK what you think.

Comment: [Sorry if someone already suggested it; I didn't read all the comments] - I'm pretty sure I'm going to pull fire towards me, but still... Did you consider dropping the indices before your n00K records and re-building them upon completion. Of course, rebuilding indices also takes time, but I have the hunch that it may be measurably shorter that updating it n00K times for each insert. Just an idea...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this still needs an answer, but I recently had a similar issue when moving over a lot of data from a duplicate table from one server to another. I've modified what I did for use with your example.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @MyVariable_I AS INT = 15

insert_more_rows:
INSERT INTO ExistingTable (
    Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7
)
SELECT TOP 100
    Field1
    , @MyVariable_I
    , Field3
    , 0
    , Field5
    , NULL
    , Field7
FROM
    SomeOtherTable WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE 
    Field1 > ( SELECT MAX( Field1 ) FROM ExistingTable )
ORDER BY
    Field1;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE Field1 > ( SELECT MAX( Field1 ) FROM ExistingTable ) )
    GOTO insert_more_rows;
```

The idea is to break the insert up into manageable "batches" so you don't kill your server and lock up the database while it runs.

In this case, I'm assuming "Field1" is a unique id in "SomeOtherTable" that is being inserted into "ExistingTable". With this assumption and ordering my SELECT on Field1, I can determine if more records need to be inserted into ExistingTable by comparing its Field1 max value to SomeOtherTable.Field1 values. Then, if more rows remain to be inserted, `GOTO insert_more_rows` is called, inserting another 100 rows.